# Check for success of $wpdb->update() correctly

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

My code is

```
if( $wpdb->update($tableName,array('opt_value'=>$cInfo),array('opt_name'=>'showWeatherWidget')))
    //show success message
else
    // show failure message
```

This is not correct, `$wpdb->update()` returns false if it doesn't change any data, but there were no errors. Can someone tell me the proper way to display a success message that a field was updated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing errors with $wpdb update](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16382/showing-errors-with-wpdb-update)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct way is with `=== FALSE` which differentiates from equalling zero, which is what a succesful query with no results returns.

```
if( $wpdb->update($tableName,array('opt_value'=>$cInfo),array('opt_name'=>'showWeatherWidget')) === FALSE)
    //show failure message
else
    // show success message
```

Comment: This conflicts with this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6529242/wpdb-what-does-it-return-on-fail which says : if ($result === false) // Fail -- the "===" operator compares type as well as value

Comment: This is proven in my code - I vouch (and +1) this answer! Thanks JMC!