# wpdb->update error

Tags: wpdb

I am trying to update the value of an entry in the gravity forms detail table.

I am simply trying to update the 'date' field inside of an entry. Here is my query:

```
        $update_date = $wpdb->update( 
            'wp_rg_lead_detail', 
            array( 
                'value' => the_date('Y-m-d')
            ), 
            array( 
                'lead_id' => 170, 
                'field_number' => 16
            )
        );
```

It seems to be returning an error. This is the first time I am using $wpdb at all, so I may be doing something wrong here. Thanks!

Comment: try `$wpdb->prefix . 'rg_lead_detail'` for the table name

Comment: "___seems to be___" or actually _is_ returning an error. If returning an error _what is that error_?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using the `the_date()` function, but if you must, make sure it returns the value instead of echo-ing it.

So instead of this part:

```
 array( 
     'value' => the_date('Y-m-d')
 ),
```

try this one:

```
array( 
    'value' => the_date( 'Y-m-d', $before = '', $after = '', $echo = 0 );
),
```

To catch the update error, check out this question: [Showing errors with $wpdb update](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16382/showing-errors-with-wpdb-update)

In general also remember to activate `WP_DEBUG` on your test site: [Debugging in wordPress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress).

Comment: @EHerman Any progress on this problem?